# When solving $\sin^2 x = \frac14(2+ \sqrt 3)$, is it better to substitute $\sin^2x=1-\cos^2x$ or $\sin^2x=\frac12(1-\cos 2 x)?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am trying to evaluate
$$\sin^2 x = \frac{2+ \sqrt 3}{4}$$ where $x$ is $0$ to $2 \pi$.

For $ \sin^2 x$, I can substitute it to either:

1. $ 1 - \cos ^2 x$ (Pythagorean identity)
2. $ \frac12( 1 - \cos 2 x)$ (double angle formula)

How do I know which formula to use for this evaluation?

Comment: I believe the second option should be $\frac{1-\cos (2x)}{2}$.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy yes! thanks for spotting it

Comment: Using $1-\cos^2 x$ does not simplify equation. You can or use rule $f(x)^2 = g(x) \Leftrightarrow f(x)=\sqrt{g(x)} \lor f(x)=-\sqrt{g(x)}$ or use $\cos 2x$ substitution. You may try both and see what method gives more simple solution and more simple expression for final result.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{2+\sqrt 3}{4} = \sin^2x = \frac{1-\cos 2x}{2},$$
$$\cos 2x = 1-\frac{2+\sqrt 3}{2} = -\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}.$$

Comment: And now $2x$ is between $0$ and $4\pi$, so we get four solutions for $x$.

Comment: Which works out to $2x = \pm \frac{5\pi}{6} + 2\pi n$, or $x = \pm \frac{5\pi}{12} + \pi n$.